# bash: Different results if same function is called from sourced script or executed directly

Tags: bash

I've run into a something that I don't understand, and I've managed to reproduce the situtation in the script below.

If I source the script it fails with `head: 1: invalid number of lines`. But if the script is executed as a script it succeeds.

```
# !/bin/bash
# test.sh
function getline { 
    local line=$(cat /etc/passwd  | cut -d':' -f1 | grep --no-messages -nw "$1" | cut -d':' -f1) 
    /usr/bin/head -n $line /etc/passwd | tail -n 1  
}   

# Call the function
getline root
```

Debug output if sourced and then called (`set -x`)

```
+ getline root
++ cat /etc/passwd
++ cut -d: -f1
++ cut -d: -f1
++ grep --colour=always -niw root
+ local 'line=1'
+ tail -n 1
+ /usr/bin/head -n '1' /etc/passwd
/usr/bin/head: 1: invalid number of lines
```

Debug output if executed directly:

```
+ /tmp/test.sh
++ getline root
+++ cat /etc/passwd
+++ cut -d: -f1
+++ cut -d: -f1
+++ grep -niw root
++ local line=1
++ /usr/bin/head -n 1 /etc/passwd
++ tail -n 1
root:-:-:-:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

So it seems the `$line` assignment argument gets quoted in the first case,
`+ local 'line=1'` vs `++ local line=1`, which seems to lead to different results, why is that? Also if the `line` variable is not local the quotations move to the variable: `++ line='1'`

These results come from GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

*Edit:*

Explicitly use `/usr/bin/head` => same results.

Comment: Make sure that `head` is really something like `/usr/bin/head`, not an alias or a function from `bash_it` or something like that. otherwise it is treated wrong way if sourcing and is not if executed in a subshell.

Comment: Works properly at my `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: @theoden: Which bash version? Could you source the script with `set -x` to compare output? Sourcing in `zsh` also works for me.

Comment: [sure](http://pastebin.com/9m99eBJ9)

Answer (score 1):

There was an alias for grep to always color which screwed things up and probably left some escape sequence that didn't show up with `set -x`.

So the solution to this particular problem is to either execute grep explicitly without colors `... | grep --color=never`, bypassing the alias using `\` `... | \grep ...`.

Thanks to theoden which led me in right direction.